# How to retrieve the firstname from database using session

Tags: php

I want to display the firstname from database who login in my website - not the username of the user. 
Here's a picture of my database so I already tried query but always complains about an undefined index 
 [image: this is from database]

This is the navbar attendance only there's a another navbar too but I only example the attendance

navbar_attendance.php

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>


<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">




    <li><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Home</a></li>




     <li><a href="attendance.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Attendance Info</a></li>


        <li><a href="users.php"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Users</a></li>


    <?php 
                    include('dropdown.php');
                    ?>


    <li><a href="books.php"><i class="icon-book icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Books</a></li>


    <li><a href="member.php"><i class="icon-group icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Member</a></li>


    <li ><a href="archive.php"><i class="icon-list-alt icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Archive</a></li>


    <li><a href="utility.php"><i class="icon-cog icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Utilities</a></li>


        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="icon-signout icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>


                     <div class="pull-right">
                        <div class="admin">Welcome: <?php


    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    // dont know what put in here
    }

    ?></div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <?php include('search_form.php'); ?>
```

session.php

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){


session_start();

} ?> 

<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) {




  ?>     <script>window.location='index.php';</script> <?php


 exit();

}

$session_id=$_SESSION['id'];

?>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to retrieve *anything* from a database?  It looks like you should start with some introductory tutorials on using a database in PHP.

Comment: Don't ever ever save passwords in plain text.

Comment: @Akintunde just a creating a new website later on I will use md5 ty

Comment: Don't use md5. Use php password hash and password verify

Comment: @Akintunde ohhh why because my friend said better using md5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi you need to put this query at the place where you want to show the first name.

```
       <?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){


    session_start();

    } ?>  
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>


    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">




        <li><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Home</a></li>




         <li><a href="attendance.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Attendance Info</a></li>


            <li><a href="users.php"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Users</a></li>


        <?php 
                        include('dropdown.php');
                        ?>


        <li><a href="books.php"><i class="icon-book icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Books</a></li>


        <li><a href="member.php"><i class="icon-group icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Member</a></li>


        <li ><a href="archive.php"><i class="icon-list-alt icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Archive</a></li>


        <li><a href="utility.php"><i class="icon-cog icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Utilities</a></li>


            <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="icon-signout icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>


                         <div class="pull-right">
                            <div class="admin">Welcome: <?php


        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

 $sql="SELECT firstname FROM TABLENAME WHERE user_id='$session_id'";
     $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
    while($row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
             echo $row['firstname'];
                       }
                   }

        }

        ?></div>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <?php include('search_form.php'); ?>`
```

Comment: `session_id` is the variable that have id of person and by using session we get value on the the `navbar_attendance.php` page.

Comment: MYSQLI_NUM_ROWS() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE MYSQLI_RESULT, BOOLEAN GIVEN IN  " if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) " ty for response my friend why is it have error

Comment: Remove this answer.  sql injection waiting to happen. Also OP never indicated that they are using mysqli

Comment: did you include dataabase connection?

Comment: @Akintunde I will convert it to prevent sql injection